# Uncheck Grouping TD if one "Child" TD is Unchecked

Tags: jquery, html

[image]

Given the image above, if a user unchecks checkbox #2, I'm trying to get it to uncheck checkbox #1 as well. Currently, when I uncheck checkbox #2, my code unchecks both #1 and #3.

**HTML Code (sanitized and simplified)**

```
<!--Grouping Row 1-->
<tr id="group-id-example_insertjobname">
<td colspan="11" data-group="-b-insertjobname" data-group-level="0">
<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="" value="">
</td>
</tr>
<!--Grouping Row 1-->

<tr role="row" class="odd group-item" data-group="-b-XXX">
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td class="pay">
<input type="checkbox" name="PI0" class="Invoice Open" value="">
</td>
</tr>

<tr role="row" class="group-item" data-group="-b-XXX">
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td class="pay">
<input type="checkbox" name="PI1" class="Invoice Open" value="">
</td>
</tr>

<!--Grouping Row 2-->
<tr id="group-id-example_insertjobname">
<td colspan="11" data-group="-b-insertjobname" data-group-level="0">
<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="" value="">
</td>
</tr>
<!--Grouping Row 2-->

<tr role="row" class="odd group-item" data-group="-b-XXX">
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td class="pay">
<input type="checkbox" name="PI3" class="Invoice Open" value="">
</td>
</tr>

<tr role="row" class="group-item" data-group="-b-XXX">
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td class="pay">
<input type="checkbox" name="PI4" class="Invoice Open" value="">
</td>
</tr>
```

**Jquery Function**

```
$(function() {
    $('.pay input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
        if ($('this:checkbox:not(:checked)')) {
            $('.check').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$(function() {
    $('.pay input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {        
        if (!$(this).prop('checked')) {
            $(this).parent().parent().prevAll('tr').not('.group-item').first().find('.check').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Since the `$('.pay input[type="checkbox"]')` is not a child of the `$('.check')` you need to use `parent().parent()` to get to the same level as the other `tr` elements, `prevAll('tr').not('.group-item')` to get all previous grouping `tr` elements, get the first one found with `first()`, then you have to finally find the input with `$('.check')` which should be the one you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, Sbonkosky, I understand what you're trying to do, but I'm still not getting the nearest(or any other) .check checkboxes to uncheck when a "child" checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: @dentalhero I edited my answer with something I think should now work. I overlooked that the `.check` element was inside a `tr td`.

Comment: thanks! This now works, and I accepted your answer. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
$(this).prevAll().find('.check').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: Thanks, theLibertine, but this doesn't uncheck the nearest checkbox with a class of check (or any with a class of check for that matter).